# Concatenate alternating fixed column headers and row values

Tags: function, excel, concatenation, vba

I have a spreadsheet with fixed column headers and variable row data, I would like to create a simple tool (lets aim for 1 click) that will concatenate the column values and row data entered by the user into an attribute string (with '=' after each header and ';' after each value).

Before looks like this:

[image: Before]

After looks like this:

[image: After]

The output is required in a separate worksheet and if possible saved as a value.
The number of columns could vary so a solution that uses a defined table would be useful.

Formula used:

`=CONCATENATE(before!$A$1,"=",before!$A2,";",before!$B$1,"=",before!$B2,";",before!$C$1,"=",before!$C2,";")`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the latest Office 365?  If so the formula would be; `TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,before!$A$1:$C$1 & "=" & before!$A2:$C2)`

Comment: The above formula is an array and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: @ScottCraner Though I do have access to 365 I wouldn't be able to use it for this project. Also it seems to split the result over multiple columns rather than in 1.

Comment: It shouldn't but as I do not have access to my Office 365 at the moment to test I can't confirm.  But the reason that no one else has answered is that Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  This will require VBA in a UDF or Sub.  When I get home I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following UDF will do it:

```
Function unionText(ttl As Range, rng As Range) As String
Dim i As Long
If ttl.Cells.Count <> rng.Cells.Count Or _
    ttl.Rows.Count <> 1 Or rng.Rows.Count <> 1 Then
    unionText = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If

For i = 1 To ttl.Cells.Count
    unionText = unionText & ttl(i) & "=" & rng(i) & ";"
Next i
End Function
```

It is called in the sheet like this:

```
=unionText(before!$A$1:$C$1,before!A2:C2)
```

Then copied down

[image]

Mine is obviously on the same sheet but the formula above uses your sheet reference.

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this macro code temporary and assuming there's only one row of values :

```
Sub Macro1()

' Macro1 Macro

Range("A1").Select

Dim r As Byte
Dim c as Byte

Dim stringunion As String

r = 1

c = 1

Do While Cells(r, c) <> ""

    stringunion = stringunion & Cells(r, c).Value & "=" & Cells(r + 1, c) & ";"

    c = c + 1

Loop

MsgBox stringunion


End Sub
```

Comment: This only does the first row, you need to add another loop, or make this into a UDF then the rows can be set.

Comment: That's the reason i said assuming it only has one row of values. @pwl would tell us if needs more.

Comment: @jsanchezs note that this `Dim r, c As Byte` only declares `c` as a byte, `r` will be treated as a variant. It won't make any odds here, but it's something commonly misunderstood in VBA